# Vue.js render a bootstrap-vue component dynamically after a button is pressed

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this as part of my template

```html
 <button class="add" v-on:click="handleAdd(0)"><img id="0" src="../assets/plus.svg" /></button>
    
    <div class="objectives-list">
     <div class="objective-holder" id="0">
      <b-button v-b-toggle.ld-0 class="objective">
       <div class="short-description">I am a short description.</div>
       <b-collapse class="long-description" id="ld-0" @show="handleShow(0, 0, 0)" @hide="handleHide(0, 0, 0)">I am a long description.</b-collapse>
      </b-button>
     </div>
    </div>
```

I am trying to add a new "objective-holder" to the "objective-list" and I am having trouble figuring out how to create new b-button and b-collapse from BootstrapVue in a javascript function that is part of my .vue methods functions.

Comment: You want to create a button from a function? Generally speaking, elements are created with everything else, and shown or hidden from a function

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use a render function instead of a template, or some type of component utilizing a render function to programmatically create your button element. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#ad